# SSIS deploy package with variables using project parameters using package deployment model

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

There is an existing project(say Project1) which I am working on having 
project param like

Name - Param_Local_Dir

Value - F:\Test\Company\Process\

In a package(say Package1) this project param is used in the package variables to identify the value

Name - Pkg_Local_Dir

Value - REPLACE( @[$Project::Param_Local_Dir], "Company", "AA")

The project was deployed into SQL Server using project deployment model and it was running with no issues through a scheduled job.
Now I need to deploy the package into the SQL Server as there is some changes(Integration Services Catalog -> project1 - right click -> Deploy Packages)

When I select the package from the package deployment window, it gives following error -

### TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services

Warning: 
The variables "$Project::Param_Local_Dir" were not found in the variable colletion. The variables might not exist in the correct scope.

Error:

### 1. The expression for variable "Pkg_Local_Dir" failed evaluation. There was an error in the expression.

We are not in a condition to do the whole project deployemnt again as there are many packages and this is the only package that is changed.
Is there any way this error can be fixed in order to do a package deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project Deployment mode and Package Deployment are completely different beasts. You cannot refer **Project** parameters within a Package deployed in Package deployment mode . That is the reason you are getting the errors.
In SSIS 2016 you can [deploy single package](https://andyleonard.blog/2015/11/ssis-2016-supports-single-package-deployment/) from your project staying in Project mode, but not in SSIS 2012 or 2014.
In your case I would unload the Project from server, do necessary modifications to the package and deploy the updated Project back.

Comment: This worked for me. As an added note. If something has gone wrong. Right-click on the deployed project. Select versions. Then select a previous version if you need to roll-back.